# How can I update the base type's data to a derived class while using EF code first table per type

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

//here is my data models:

```
public class People
{
    public int PeopleID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("User")]
public class User : People
{
    [Required]
    public string LoginName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PassWord { get; set; }

}
```

//and i stored an item into the People table

context.People.Add(new People { Name = "Jack" });

context.SaveChanges();

//and now "Jack" is promoted as an user of this system
//how can I update his data and let him has is LoginName and Password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common design mistake.

Objects can't change their type; you shouldn't be using inheritance in this case.

Instead, the `User` can have a reference to a `Person` (another hint: your entity names should be singular, regardless of what you name the table)

Comment: thank you very much,your answer hit the nail on the head，that relly helpful

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to declare discriminator column. For example PeopleType which couln't discriminate users from all peolple by specific value.

So in your scenatio you will need to create Jack as User but you could assecc it as item of people

```
[Table("People")] 
public class People 
{ 
    public int PeopleID { get; set; } 

    [Required] 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public int Type { get; set; }
} 

public class User : People 
{ 
    [Required] 
    public string LoginName { get; set; } 

    [Required] 
    public string PassWord { get; set; }

}
```

Overide it in DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
            modelBuilder.Entity<People>().Map<User>(m => { m.Requires("PoepleType").HasValue(1 /* any value you like */); })
}
```